# Configuring Liferay 7.2 OpenID Connect for Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, liferay-7

I have a fresh Liferay 7.2 and Keycloak 7 install
I created a Keycloak Client for Liferay
I enable Openid Connect in Liferay
In Liferay I configure an OpenID Connect provider with the Keycloak OpenID Connect discovery endpoint

In Liferay
I click Login, Login is presented
I click OpenID Connect, OpenID Connect Login page is presented
I click Login with the Keycloak provider selected, the browser is redirected to the Keycloak log in page
I enter my user and password and Click log in
My browser is redirected back to Liferay
In the Liferay the console looks like this https://gist.github.com/smitopher/ca8bcb2ccb564eff3a42a1944e8daed7

and the browser shows a Liferay Internal Server Error message

Any suggestions?

Some further debugging shows that When Liferay calls the Keycloak token endpoint, Keycloak returns a 400 http status and an invalid grant message.

Comment: `Unable to validate tokens` -> Is Liferay able to reach Keycloak OpenID Connect discovery endpoint?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it would not redirect

Comment: Do you have more detail on what the Keycloak token endpoint error shows?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem but later stumbled across [a blog post](https://lifedev-solutions.blogspot.com/2019/10/liferay-keycloak-integration-using.html) showing a successful configuration which I've reproduced with Liferay 7.2 + Keycloak 4.8.

The key difference between the failures and successes appears to be skipping auto-discovery and instead to populate the individual settings directly. It would appear that Liferay doesn't like something in Keycloaks discovery endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend updating the Keycloak version and checking the correct Liferay configuration by consulting the official Liferay documentation [Authenticating with OpenID Connect](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028711312-Authenticating-with-OpenID-Connect). You can also consult the article [How to connect Keycloak and Liferay via OpenID Connect](https://techblog.smc.it/en/2021-10-15/how-to-connect-keycloak-liferay-openid-connect)

Remember that Keycloak and Liferay must be able to communicate with each other via the HTTP / HTTPS protocol.